# CRUD of a model within another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Post CRUD. On show.html.erb for Post, I want CRUD for comment. I am using devise for User. I have tried what others have suggested elsewhere on stack overflow but it has not worked. It keeps saying @comment is empty. I'd appreciate your help.

comments controller

```rb
    def new
        @user = current_user
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.new
        render :template => 'posts/show'
    end

    def create
        @user = current_user
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.new(post_params)
        render :template => 'posts/show'

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to post_path(post.id), notice: "Success!~"
        else 
            redirect_to post_path(post.id), alert: "Failure!"
        end

    end

    private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
        end
```

show.html.erb (within posts folder)

```rb
<%= form_for([@user, @post, @comment]) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why are you showing us `show.html.erb` for `posts` and the `comments_controller`? Show us the `posts_controller`, since that is what's rendering `show.html.erb`.

Comment: @jvillian Thank you for your input. I don't think you understood or perhaps I didn't explain clearly. The posts controller's show action has only this: ```@goal = Goal.find(params[:id])```. Without the part for adding comments, that much is working fine. What I'm having trouble is not with posts controller but with comments controller, which is directed to show.html.erb of posts controller. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no need for a `render` and then `redirect_to post_path...`, if you redirect to `post_path` you indeed need to share `posts_controller` `show` action as suggested, to see what is actually retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you, you want to have the CRUD actions for comments in the show view of a post. It's called nested routing or just nested models.

From you `posts/show` view I can see from your form for you also nested the posts inside the users. That's not necessary. As a general guideline, don't nest models more than one level. I guess in your app posts belong to a user, and you're using devise. So by the creation of a post you can just assign the `current_user` to the post and then you don't need to nest them inside each other.

Now for your questions: Since you have the form for a new comment on the show page of post, you need to have the code from your `comments_controller#new` in the `posts_controller#show`. Why? Because you use the instance variable `@comment` in the form_for. If in your `posts_controller` there is no such `@comment` defined,it will throw the error.
Once your form is then filled and submitted a post request to `comments_controller#create` is made, where you save the code and redirect to the `post#show`.